# How to compare multiple symbols programatically on a single tradingview chart?

Tags: tradingview-api

I need to create a chart similar to what is shown and explained at https://www.tradingview.com/wiki/Compare .

at https://www.tradingview.com/widget/advanced-chart/ I can create a custom chart but there is no option for  multi-symbol chart.

There are more customization options at https://github.com/mmmy/css3demos/wiki/Charts-Customization-101 but no multi-symbol option.

This can of course be done manually. But it takes a lot of time to add 20 symbols every time I reload the page.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it by using createStudy() method [detail here](https://github.com/mmmy/css3demos/wiki/Chart-Methods#createstudyname-forceoverlay-lock-inputs-callback-overrides) after Chart ready.
For example:
`widget.chart().createStudy('Compare', false, false, ["open", 'APPL'])`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I misunderstood what you want.

You wrote "at https://www.tradingview.com/widget/advanced-chart/ there is no option for multi-symbol chart.", but clicking on the balance icon pops up a window that let you add symbols (see flag on "overlay the main chart") or compare companies as shown in https://www.tradingview.com/wiki/Compare.

Is this what you are looking for?

[image: Multi-symbol-option]

Comment: That's what I am looking for. But I need it to be done using code not the UI.

Comment: @MarekJavůrek Perhaps, another solution is to find a way to save the chart. There is a save option on Tradingview platform charts, but I can't find it on embedded charts.

Comment: Did you figure out a way to compare it through code.