# Tradingview Advanced Charts API Add 2nd Data Series

Tags: next.js, tradingview-api

I am integrating Tradingview Advanced Charts into a project, however I am running into some difficulty with displaying 2 series' at once. Also, I am using a custom deafeed implementation on my own UDF server. Here is what I am trying to achieve [(this was done through the ui)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qTIwN.png)

To be clear, I am trying to implement this *in code*. I already know how to implement this through the UI as is shown above.

### What have I tried?

So far I have tried following tradingview's own documentation on the topic [here](https://www.tradingview.com/charting-library-docs/latest/ui_elements/indicators/#add-and-compare-new-series), as well as [other stackoverflow posts about similar topics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48362045/how-to-compare-multiple-symbols-programatically-on-a-single-tradingview-chart), all of which were *not* resolved, which is why I have created this post. As far as my specific code implementation, I am currently trying the following:

#### Tradingview Configuration

```js
const widgetOptions: ChartingLibraryWidgetOptions = {
            symbol: symbol,
            // BEWARE: no trailing slash is expected in feed URL
            datafeed: new (window as any).Datafeeds.UDFCompatibleDatafeed(
                process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_USE_DEV_UDF_ENDPOINT == "true" ? process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_DEV_UDF_ENDPOINT : process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_PROD_UDF_ENDPOINT,
                undefined,
                {
                    maxResponseLength: 100,
                    expectedOrder: "latestFirst",
                }
            ),
            interval,
            container: chartContainerRef.current,
            library_path: library_path,
            locale: locale,
            disabled_features: ["use_localstorage_for_settings"],
            enabled_features: ["study_templates", "compare_symbol_search_spread_operators"],
            charts_storage_url: charts_storage_url,
            charts_storage_api_version: charts_storage_api_version,
            client_id: client_id,
            user_id: user_id,
            fullscreen: fullscreen,
            autosize: autosize,
            theme: "dark"
        };

widgetRef.current = new widget(widgetOptions);
```

#### Adding Second Series

```js
await this.widgetRef!.current!.activeChart().createStudy("Compare", false, false, { symbol: "0x8dbee21e8586ee356130074aaa789c33159921ca"})
```

I have been able to confirm that the chart is requesting the correct data, through looking at the logs on my UDF server. Also, the chart is displaying the name of this second symbol, which comes from the server. When the chart attempts to load the data for this second symbol, it shows the loading symbol next to it for a few seconds before displaying a "0" with a slash through it [(see image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rv0Nv.png)